# Idiomatic way to decode hex-formatted strings in Racket Scheme or other schemes

Tags: scheme, lisp, common-lisp, racket

My input data is a hex-formatted string without restriction on the length. I need to process the bytes individually. As an example, for "AABBCCDDEEFF" I want to process AA, then BB, CC, DD, EE, FF.

Using Common Lisp, we can use LOOP:

```
(loop for (a b) on list do [processing])
```

In Racket Scheme, I wrote this solution:

```
(define (split-string str)
  (let ((bit #t)
        (char-1 null)
        (char-2 null)
        (result '()))
    (for ((char str))
      (if bit
          (begin
            (set! bit #f)
            (set! char-1 char))
          (begin
            (set! bit #t)
            (set! char-2 char)
            (set! result (cons (~a char-1 char-2) result)))))
    ;; return
    (reverse result)))

(split-string "AABBCCDDEEFF")
;; '("AA" "BB" "CC" "DD" "EE" "FF")
```

I feel like this is not idiomatic Racket or Scheme code. I wrote a second solution:

```
(define (split-string2 str)
 (bytes->list (integer->integer-bytes (string->number str 16) 8 false)))

(split-string2 "AABBCCDDEEFF")
;; '(255 238 221 204 187 170 0 0)
```

What is the idiomatic way to perform this kind of operations in Racket Scheme and more generally in Lisp?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a bunch of ways of doing this in Racket (as opposed to Scheme more generally): the notions you want are [sequences, streams and generators](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/sequences_streams.html?q=sequences%20and%20streams).

First of all a function to compute hex digits from characters (this may exist in Racket, but I was too lazy to find it, and this works):

```
(define (char->hex-digit c)
  ;; Turn a character into a hex digit
  (cond [(char<=? #\0 c #\9)
         (- (char->integer c) (char->integer #\0))]
        [(char<=? #\A c #\F)
         (+ 10 (- (char->integer c) (char->integer #\A)))]
        [(char<=? #\a c #\f)
         (+ 10 (- (char->integer c) (char->integer #\a)))]
        [else
         (error 'char->hex-digit "~A is not a hex character" c)]))
```

Now here is a simple-minded approach to turning a hex string into a list of bytes which works by creating two sequences from the string, one of which picks out the high and the other the low digit in each pair:

```
(define (hex-string->byte-list hs)
  (for/list ([h (in-string hs 0 #f 2)]
             [l (in-string hs 1 #f 2)])
    (+ (* (char->hex-digit h) 16) (char->hex-digit l))))
```

Obviously depending on which variant of `for` you use you can construct different results.

Examples:

```
> (hex-string->byte-list "F00D")
'(240 13)
> (hex-string->byte-list "0102030405060708090a0b0C0D0F")
'(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 15)
> (hex-string->byte-list "01xa")
; char->hex-digit: x is not a hex character [,bt for context]
```

Another approach is to use `in-slice`:

```
(define (hex-string->byte-list hs)
  (for/list ([hl (in-slice 2 (in-string hs))])
    (+ (* (char->hex-digit (first hl)) 16) (char->hex-digit (second hl)))))
```

And there are lots of other ways of doing this, including creating your own sequence or stream types, so you could write `(for/list ([b (in-hex-stream-bytes ...)]) b)`.

Comment: I am now more clear about the Racket's sequences, it is very powerful.
It was very helpful, thank you!

Comment: For anyone wondering, you can do the hex digit to number conversion this way:
`
  (define (char->hex-digit c)
    (string->number
     (format "#x~a" c)))
`

Answer (score 3):

Note that the Common Lisp version would not work since the input is a string; in order to use the same approach you should first convert the string to a list of characters; secondly, you would need to add a `by` directive to advance over the list by `cddr`, i.e. skipping the already read `b`.
That would finally look like:

```
(loop
   for (a b) on (coerce "AABBCCDDEEFF" 'list) by #'cddr
   collect (parse-integer (coerce (vector a b) 'string)
                          :radix 16))

=> (170 187 204 221 238 255)
```

But, this is a bit wasteful, `parse-integer` admits `:start` and `:end` arguments, so you do not need to allocate any intermediate list or string (apart for the last `collect`; you could skip it too and just process the value directly):

```
(loop
   with string = "AABBCCDDEEFF"
   with size = (length string)
   initially (assert (evenp size))
   for start from 0 by 2
   for end from 2 by 2 upto size
   collect (parse-integer string :start start :end end :radix 16))

=> (170 187 204 221 238 255)
```

Comment: My problem is not related to conversion from hex to byte.
It is about how to iterate 2 hex character per 2 hex character in Scheme.

Answer (score 0):

One of the idiomatic ways would be to use recursion (preserving the same functionality as your `split-string`) as follows:

```
(define (split-string-recur str)
  (cond [(or (string=? str "") (string=? "" (substring str 1))) '()]
        [else (cons (substring str 0 2) (split-string-recur (substring str 2)))]))
```

and a tail-recursive version:

```
(define (split-string-trecur str)
  (define (split-string-recur str acc)
    (cond [(or (string=? str "") (string=? "" (substring str 1))) acc]
        [else (split-string-recur (substring str 2) (append acc (list (substring str 0 2))))]))
  (split-string-recur str '()))
```

The `for/list` approach with `in-slice` on `in-string` sequence (mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58953129/8891889)) is also an idiomatic approach.

Note that we can also use a small interface on strings like the following to make it more readable:

```
(module string-util typed/racket
  (provide (all-defined-out))

  (: empty-string? : (-> String Boolean))
  (define (empty-string? s)
    (string=? "" s))

  (: string-first : (-> String String))
  (define (string-first s)
    (substring s 0 1))

  (: string-last : (-> String String))
  (define (string-last  s)
    (substring s (- (string-length s) 1) (string-length s)))

  (: string-rest : (-> String String))
  (define (string-rest  s)
    (substring s 1 (string-length s))))

(require 'string-util)

(define (split-string-recur str)
  (cond [(or (empty-string? str) (empty-string? (string-rest str))) '()]
        [else (cons (string-append (string-first str) (string-first (string-rest str)))
                    (split-string-recur (string-rest (string-rest str))))]))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CL-USER 2 > (defun split-string (string)
              (loop for i from 0 below (length string) by 2
                    collect (subseq string i (+ i 2))))
SPLIT-STRING

CL-USER 3 > (split-string "AABBCCDDEEFF")
("AA" "BB" "CC" "DD" "EE" "FF")

CL-USER 4 > (mapcar (lambda (s) (parse-integer s :radix 16)) *)
(170 187 204 221 238 255)
```